# Android Camera Preview works fine on emulator crashes on device

Tags: android

I'm trying to get camera preview and take a part of it to show on a ImageView. This code works fine on emulator but crashes on device with following error:

> A/libc(2659): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x42e612a9 (code=2), thread
>   2659

I looked many questions related to SIGSEGV error but I couldn't find any solutions for this problem. My device and emulator are Android 4.1.2

```
Size sizeOrgnl;
Rect newRect;
ByteArrayOutputStream newStream;
Bitmap newPicture;
ImageView imgView;  

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int w, int h) {

     camera=Camera.open();
        if(camera!=null)
        { try
        {
            List<Size> cmszs=camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
            for(int i=0;i<cmszs.size();i++)
            {
                if(cmszs.get(i).width<500&&(cmszs.get(i).width>400))
                {camera.getParameters().setPictureSize(cmszs.get(i).width, cmszs.get(i).height);}

            }
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(arg0);
            camera.stopPreview();
              camera.startPreview();
             Thread.sleep(500);
             newStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    if(sizeOrgnl==null)
                    {sizeOrgnl=camera.getParameters().getPictureSize();
                    newRect=new Rect(sizeOrgnl.width/2-20,sizeOrgnl.height/2-20,sizeOrgnl.width/2+20,sizeOrgnl.height/2+20);                    
                    }
                    YuvImage    img = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, sizeOrgnl.width, sizeOrgnl.height, null);
                    newStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    img.compressToJpeg(newRect, 90, newStream);                 

                    newPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(newStream.toByteArray() , 0, newStream.size());
                   imgView.setImageBitmap(newPicture);  

                }
            });     

        } catch(Exception e){}
        }
```

The error occurs on this line (but only on device):

```
img.compressToJpeg(newRect, 90, newStream);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Even i'm fed up with this `SIGSEGV` its the native code crash that's all i know coz don't know NDK development any answers are appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Actually I had but I can't find the projet now as it was a demo. As far as I remember I cancelled taking a portion of picture and I used all data. I think the problem was about converting and cropping the image.